# Copy phone memory by adb

Tags: adb, copymemory

When I want to copy my phone data to my PC using these commands:

Terminal 1

```
$BUSYBOX nc -l -p 5555 -e $BUSYBOX dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0
```

Terminal 2

```
nc 127.0.0.1 5555 | pv -i 0.5 > $HOME/mmcblk0.raw
```

I get info that:

```
1|ASUS_I001_1:/ # /system/xbin/busybox nc -l -p 5555 -e /system/xbin/busybox d>
dd: can't open '/dev/block/mmcblk0': **No such file or directory**
```

Why?

Comment: Please remove the cygwin tag.

Comment: does the `/dev/block/mmcblk0` exist ?

Comment: I can't found it so it does not exist but now I go forward and try copy partition by partition but now I have new problem:

Comment: I try copy: /dev/block/sda12 for example and get that.

Comment: /system/xbin/busybox nc –l –p 5555 –e /system/xbin/busybox dd if=/dev/block/sda12                         <
65536+0 records in
65536+0 records out
33554432 bytes (32.0MB) copied, 0.148482 seconds, 215.5MB/s